# Best use of checkbox and question formulation

Tags: usability, user-expectation

These two forms yield the same result in my database. Which one of these two "setups" would you consider the most elegant and/or correct way of asking whether people would like to be contacted by SMS or not, and why...?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you HAVE to collect the mobile number? I see the asterisk, which I presume signifies a mandatory field.

Comment: In this case it is mandatory.

Comment: Are you aware of data protection laws? GDPR requires opt-in.

Answer (score 3):

In that case (your comment) would go with the second option.

This is because it is a positive action, for which the user is making a choice to 'do' something, not tick a box to confirm nothing should happen.

Answer (score 2):

The second option, same reason as @DarrylGodden already gave.

I would additionally recommend rephrasing the message to: **Please contact me by SMS**

Comment: agreed, "I would like to be.." could work as well